# What am I missing in this VBA code to make Goal Seek work down a column?

Tags: excel, vba

I made this macro to make goal seek go down the G column to automate pricing on a list of products. It worked once on another workbook and then would not work again when I pasted it to a new workbook.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+z
'
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    
With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lastRow
            .Range("I" & i).GoalSeek Goal:=0.35, ChangingCell:=.Range("G" & i)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

I moved the macro to another workbook and now it is no longer working, I think it could be something dealing with the difference in versions or a simple mistake, I am just not well versed enough in VBA to figure it out. Thank you for any help!

Comment: What sort of "Not Working" are you seeing - error message, incorrect value, blank results, etc? Do you have a suitable formula in Column I?  Have you tried doing a "manual" Goal Seek (Data → Data Tools → What-if Analysis → Goal Seek) on 1 row of data to confirm that it works correctly?

Comment: I get a runtime error 1004 for the fourth line from the bottom. Yes I have a profit margin formula of =(D2-G2)/D2, and repeating as it goes down the column, =(D3-G3)/D3 ect. Yes the manual goal seek works.

Comment: Just to double check, the value in Column D on that fourth-line-from-the-bottom wouldn't happen to be 0, would it?

Comment: No, all the values are non negative. Also if I clear the column where I have some manual goal seeks done and try to run the macro I get an error for the code it will not run. The problem I think is in the code if several manual attempts work. The Runtime 1004 error is in the fourth line from the bottom of the code above, sorry for not making that clear enough.

Comment: I didn't ask about negative numbers; negative numbers are not an issue for your formula.  However, if any of the values in Column D are **exactly** 0, then you will get an error, because it becomes `=(0-G?)/0` for that row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's rather crude, but this macro should Goal-Seek for the rows that work, and give you slightly more information about where/why you are getting errors:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+z
'
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    
With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lastRow
            If IsError(.Cells(i, 9).Value) Or Not(IsNumeric(.Cells(i, 9).Value)) Then
                MsgBox "The formula in Cell " & .Cells(i, 9).Address & " does not currently return a Number." & vbCrLf & "Formula: " & .Cells(i, 9).Formula & vbCrLf & "Value: " & .Cells(i, 9).Value, vbCritical
            Else
                On Error GoTo HadError
                .Range("I" & i).GoalSeek Goal:=0.35, ChangingCell:=.Range("G" & i)
                If False Then
HadError:
                    On Error GoTo -1
                    MsgBox "Unable to locate the Goal for the formula in Cell " & .Cells(i, 9).Address & vbCrLf & "Formula: " & .Cells(i, 9).Formula, vbCritical
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

However, since your Formula is (per comments) `=(D2-G2)/D2`, you could always dispense with the VBA and use Maths:

```
=(D2-G2)/D2 'Goal = 0.35
(D2-G2)/D2 = 0.35 'Combine
D2 - G2 = 0.35 * D2 'Multiply by D2
G2 - D2 = -0.35 * D2 'Multiply by -1
G2 = D2 - (0.35 * D2) 'Add D2
G2 = (1 - 0.35) * D2 'Factorise
G2 = 0.65 * D2 'Simplify
```

So, just put the formula `=0.65 * D2` into Cell G2, and fill down…

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this question, is to not activate goal seek from a vba macro.  I would code the macro to seek the goal, it wouldn't be a lot of code, and a simple, but slow loop.  Generally I only use spreadsheet tools directly in the spreadsheet, and code in vba, and try to avoid mixing them together.

Something like:

```
For i = 2 To lastRow
   For j = 0 To 100 Step 0.1
       Cells(i, 7) = j
       If Round(cells(i, 9), 2) = 0.35 Then Exit For
   Next
Next
```

However, goal seek is a primitive trial and error tool I used it once or twice about 20 years ago and never again, if your spreadsheet is big enough, your script could take a very long time to run unless you try to include some mathematics in your solution.  Can the equations be rearranged to give the desired value in column G for the outcome of 0.35 in column I.